# using gdal to merge Sentinel 5p projected tiff files without the overlapping at borders?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, mapping, gdal-merge, sentinel-5p

I have used [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) for extracting Sentinel 5p `L2__AER_AI` data product to 14 tiff files in EPSG:4326 CRS.

These projected tiff files can be gotten from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AHuH6n-O3IkTOkhHjlw2XBtOCUYXIfkE?usp=sharing

Then, I used `gdal_merge.py` for merging them:

```
 gdal_merge.py -a_nodata 9.96920999999999943e+36 -o merged.tiff file_1.tiff file_2.tiff ...
```

The output looks correct, but it has **pixel overlapping** at the borders (opened on QGIS and applied style with pseudo color palette), and I don't know what is the best way to flatten these pixels properly.

[image]

Comment: You can do basic mosaicking using `gdalwarp` using the `-cutline` option, which takes a vector datasource which you would have to come up with to represent the desired image regions. That would allow you to blend the overlap areas, using `-cblend`.  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

Comment: @mikewatt I'm not sure I understood your answer. You mentioned the -cutline with a datasource (which is a WKT polygon?). The problem is, I don't have the polygon (each tiff file needs its owned polygon?), only 14 tiff files, they are overlapping to their neighbors at the borders.

Comment: Right, the cutlines would be polygons, probably one for each tiff file.  You'd have to create those somehow, either by manually digitizing them or coming up with some automated workflow to identify the overlap areas.  It's not a great answer to your question, just a suggestion of a path you could explore